# Linq : Select Different Object Left Join

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I've tow contracts and one query I want to select one of them based on join result , without using where clause,

```
from a in pContext
     join c in vContext 
       on a.id equals c.id into av 
     from lav in av.DefaultIfEmpty()
if(lav != null )
{
   select new DTO1()
  {
   a.id,
   a.name,
   lav.description
  }
}
else
{
 select new DTO2()
 {
  a.id,
  a.name
 }
}
```

Comment: `lav` is an object, how do you expect this to compare to zero?

Comment: It's not null , it's my bad , cause if lav is null it's throw `NullReferenceException` , I've used lav.description != null ? lav.description : "Not found "
but it's useless.

Comment: If it is EF Core, you can just use first expression, EF Core will handle nulls. In other cases you have to use ternary operator `? :`

Comment: I've used ternary operator but it throws `NullReferenceException`

Comment: So post real query, not this simplified demonstration. You have  missed important parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from a in pContext
     join c in vContext 
       on a.id equals c.id into av 
     from lav in av.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new DTO()
  {
   id = a.id,
   name = a.name,
   description = lav != null ? lav.description : "No Specified"
  }
```

The solution is based on **Svyatoslav Danyliv** comment using ternary operator but with different condition to avoid the `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

EF Core translates LINQ "left join" to SQL left join and you do not need to handle nulls in this case, because it expects values from DbDataReader. Simple projection should work:

```cs
var query =
    from a in pContext
    join c in vContext on a.id equals c.id into av 
    from lav in av.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new DTO1
    {
        a.id,
        a.name,
        lav.description
    };
```

Comment: It's throw `NullReferenceException` , lav is null .

Comment: What is `pContext` and `vContext`? It is just a List?

Comment: pContext & vContext they are awaited list comes from external service and they returned data , pContext has an Id match's the id in vContext and I want to  display joined data from those tow list if they are matched or not. when I dismiss  left join only getting linked data,